# How can I make it so people can't join on my minecraft pe world even when they are on the wifi zone?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I really need help because people are killing me and steeling my stuff.

Comment: If you're only playing singleplayer, turn off Wifi

Comment: or just don't open to lan